# Сортировка SQL-запроса по 5 столбцам

Tags: sql, сортировка, запрос

Всем привет, прощу помощи!

Есть таблица данных, требуется выполнить сортировку по нескольким: building, floor, room, name(по алфавиту), при этом работник с type = 'руководитель', быть первым в разрезе своего кабинета(room).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо за Ваши ответы

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `order by` для сортировки, `case when type='руководитель then 0 else 1 end'` для поднятия руководителя. http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_order_by_clause.html